# How to retry http call x times if JSON doesn't contain certain fields?

Tags: python, json, http

I have a below code which takes few parameters and makes URL for each `ipAddress` using `make_status_url` and then execute that url to get JSON string as the response.

Now I check the `status` response to see if JSON contains certains fields or not and basis on that I throw exception. Below code works fine.

```
make_status_url = (
    ENDPOINT_PATH + 'kv/app-name/{instance:}/status/{ip:}?raw'
).format

class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass

def validate(
    session: Session, env: str, instance: str, new_config: str, action: str,
    machine: Dict[str, object],
):
    ip = machine['IPAddress']
    with session.get(
        make_status_url(env=env, instance=instance, ip=ip)
    ) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        status = response.json()

    prefix = f'{action} failed for {ip}: '

    # check 'status' json response for necessary fields and their values
    if action == 'push':
        if not status.get('isPushed'):
            raise ValidationError(prefix + 'not pushed')
        if status.get('currentCfg') != new_config:
            raise ValidationError(prefix + 'configuration mismatch')
    elif action == 'verify' and status.get('activeCfg') != new_config:
        raise ValidationError(prefix + 'configuration mismatch')
```

**Problem Statement**

As you can see I check `status` resposne to validate certain fields and their values. If they don't have it then I throw exception immediately. Instead of that I wanted to retry for 5 times if `status` response doesn't have those fields in it.

- Call IP url and check status response.
- If status response doesn't have necessary fields in it, try calling url again and check status response again.
- Repeat this for 5 times and after 5 times it is still not there then exit with the current error message that I already have.
- Between each retry, sleep for 50 milliseconds.

How can I do this efficiently in my above python code? This is what I have tried but I am not sure whether it is the right way of doing it or if there is any better way?

```
def validate(
    session: Session, env: str, instance: str, new_config: str, action: str,
    machine: Dict[str, object],
):
    ip = machine['IPAddress']
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            with session.get(
                make_status_url(env=env, instance=instance, ip=ip)
            ) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                status = response.json()

            prefix = f'{action} failed for {ip}: '

            # check 'status' json response for necessary fields and their values
            if action == 'push':
                if not status.get('isPushed'):
                    raise ValidationError(prefix + 'not pushed')
                if status.get('currentCfg') != new_config:
                    raise ValidationError(prefix + 'configuration mismatch')
            elif action == 'verify' and status.get('activeCfg') != new_config:
                raise ValidationError(prefix + 'configuration mismatch')
            sleep(0.05)
            return
        except Exception as e:
            raise from e
```

Comment: Have you tried calling this function in a loop? Basically you just need to convert your bullet points to Python code. Based on the code you have shown you should be capable of doing this. What was the problem?

Comment: Sorry I just added what I have tried so far but since I am kinda new to Python so wasn't sure if this is the right way of doing it or it can designed in better way. I just used for loop and break out of it if successfully otherwise keep trying for x number of times. I am not sure whether this can be done differently in Python in much more clean and efficient way if there is any?

Comment: It looks reasonable. Does it work? If it works, you could ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).